# Do Vishnu , Shiva and Brahma always keep meditating ? And What about Krishna?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, krishna, brahma, meditation

Do Vishnu in Baikunth , Shiva in Kailash and Brahma in Brahmloka always keep meditating ?

And What about Krishna.  He lives in Go-Loka with Radha. What does he constantly keep doing in Go-Loka ?

Answer (score 1):

- Brahma of Satya Loka and Vishnu of Vaikuntha.:

> *सर्वकरणानि मनसि सम्प्रतिष्ठाप्य ध्यानं विष्णुः प्राणं मनसि सह करणैः सम्प्रतिष्ठाप्य ध्याता रुद्रः प्राणं मनसि सहकरणैर्नादान्ते परमात्मनि सम्प्रतिष्ठाप्य ध्यायीतेशानं प्रध्यायितव्यं सर्वमिदं |(Atharvashika Upanishad 2:1).*
>
> *“The pranava (the sound of Om) makes all the souls to bow before it. It is the one and only one which has to be meditated upon as the four Vedas and the birth place of all devas. **One who meditates like that goes away from all sorrows and fears and gets the power to protect all others who approach him. It is because of this meditation only that Lord Vishnu who is spread every where, wins over all others. It is because Lord Brahma controlled all his organs and meditated upon it, he attained the position of the creator. Even Lord Vishnu , parks his mind in the sound (Om) of the place of Paramathma (ultimate soul) and meditates upon Îsâna.** , who is most proper to be worshipped. All this is only proper in case of Îsâna. ”.*

- Rudra of Kailasha.:

> *“Sarve Rudram Bhajantyeva Rudrah Kinchid Bhajennahi Svaatmana Bhaktavaatsalyaad Bhajatyeva kadachana" (Shiva Purana, Kotirudra Samhita 7:15).*
>
> *"**Everyone worships Rudra but Rudra doesn’t worship anyone. For the sake of devotees he meditates on himself**”*

- Krishna of Dwapar Yuga.:

> *“sa eṣa rudra bhaktaś ca keśavo rudra saṃbhavaḥ | sarvabhūtabhavaṃ jñātvā liṅge ‘rcayati yaḥ prabhum | tasminn abhyadhikāṃ prītiṃ karoti vṛṣabhadhvajaḥ |” (MBH 7:172:89-90).*
>
> *“**Kesava (Krishna) is that devoted worshipper of Rudra who has sprung from Rudra himself. Kesava always worships the Lord Siva, regarding his Linga emblem to be the origin of the universe. The God having the bull for his mark cherisheth greater regard for Kesava”**.*

- Krishna of Goloka.:

> *maduktamiti saṃdhārya śirasā rādhayā saha | śrīkṛṣṇo'modadatyaṃtaṃ svasthānamagamatsudhīḥ |
> nyaṣṭhātāṃ sabhayaṃ tatra madārādhanatatparau | (Sri Shiva Maha Purana 2.5:5:31:13b-14).*
>
> "*What I told thus Śrīkṛṣṇa and Rādhā accepted readily. Śrīkṛṣṇa the intelligent rejoiced and returned to his abode. **There (in Goloka) they (Śrīkṛṣṇa and Rādhā) engaged themselves in propitiating me (Bhagawan Shiva)** and bidding their time."*

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..